# How to reference projects not in same root

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, shared-libraries, perforce, projects-and-solutions

Like most people we use third party libraries. Many have source which we keep in our VCS.

Currently if these libraries are updated, we need to pull the source manually and rebuild the binaries.

I am trying to find a way to instead reference them from the various solutions that use them, so that they will be automatically pulled from source control when you pull the dependant project, and automatically built if they are out of date. It would also be nice to be able to debug into them with the provided source.

The first problem I am having is that the libraries are not in the same solution root as the dependant projects. eg.

```
\Libraries
 \External
  \Lib1
   Lib1.sln
\Products
 \Product1
  Product1.sln
```

Attempting to add `Lib1.csproj` to my `Product1` solution gives me the warning:

> The project that you are attempting to add to source control may cause
>   other source control users to have difficulty opening this solution or
>   getting newer versions of it. To avoid this problem, add the project
>   from a location below the binding root (C:\depot\Products\Products1) 
>   of the other source controlled projects in the solution.

If I ignore this then I can set up build dependencies properly, but it still doesn't allow pulling the entire source tree in one go.

I was wondering how other people have third party libraries set up, particularly when there is source code. (We are using Perforce but I guess the question is relevant for any VCS)

Comment: I am not familiar with Perforce, but what I would do is place the source of all third party libraries in one central location in the VCS, then link them into the checkouts of the projects that require them using something similar to [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html); you can specify the external checkout location anywhere within your actual checkout. That way, when you pull down the source for your project/solution, the third-party source gets pulled down too, and you can have project references to them as per normal.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this in perforce is to put all modules / 3rdparty-software that are about to be reused to a separate location (depot), for examples "//shared" or similar.

Products (trees in your SCMS / perforce) can "link" the required modules by mapping them into the workspace. In perforce you can do that via clientviews.
If you have many people working on many products you'll need a easy mechanism to set up a personal workspace for a product properly (without requiring the developers to setup their clientview manually).
One possibility to achieve that is a small self-written tool/script that sets up a workspace and prepares the personal clientview based on a template that is located in the product-root and that defines what modules from the "//shared" depot need to be mapped to which location in the client workspace.

We are using this practice since years and it works fine. The danger is that the clientviews can get very complex.